# Analytics goal regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am setting up an event-based goal in Google Analytics and need to use regex as there is no "contains" option.

The event label could be a couple of different things like **Ripe Bananas** or **Ripe Apples**.

So I want the regex to look for the word **Bananas** and to function like the contains option.

Just wanted to check if my assumption is correct that I can use the following for the regex?

```
/bananas/
```

or

```
bananas
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the second option you wrote because in the first there are the slashes that are not found in the labels you indicated.